# How to close fullscreen menu when clicking on a link?

Tags: jquery, frontend

I've got a 1 page website with a fullscreen navigation menu (with anchor links to elements on the page) I know how to open it, but I have no Idea on how to close the menu when clicking on a link, here is the html with my nav menu:

```
</head>
<body>
<aside>
<div id="menu-logo"></div>
<div class="hamburger-menu toggle-overlay">
      <div class="bar"></div>   
</div>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li data-menuanchor="home"><a href="#home">Nosotros</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="servicios"><a href="#servicios">Servicios</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Proyectos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Cotizador</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</aside>
<div id="content" class="fullpage">
    <section id="seccion-home" class="section up-scroll">
        <span class="background"></span>
        <header>
            <a href="#home" class="lg-principal"><span></span></a>
            <div class="hamburger-menu toggle-overlay">
              <div class="blubar"></div>    
            </div>
```

And this is my jquery script:

```
(function () {
$('.hamburger-menu').on('click', function() {
    $('.bar').toggleClass('animate');
})
})();

(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('.toggle-overlay').click(function() {
      $('aside').toggleClass('open');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I tried this, but doesn't seem to work :
    $('aside li').on('click', function(){
        $('aside').hide();
    });

Hope you can help me guys, Im very noob to web develepment.

Comment: We have no idea either, as you haven't explained this nearly enough to for us to understand it, but from the posted code, something like `$('aside').removeClass('open')` would be a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

please post more of your code, this is too limited for us to help

wild guess,

```
$('#menu li a').on('click', function(){
    $(".toggle-overlay").hide();
    $("aside").removeClass("open");
});
```

this may help.